# Extract audio from Audio wrapped into video stream ffmpeg/ffmbc

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a mov file :

```
      Metadata:
    timecode: 09:59:50:00
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, bitrate: 117714 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: dvvideo, yuv422p, 1440x1080i tff [PAR 4:3 DAR 16:9]
, 115200 kb/s, 25.00 fps
    Metadata:
      codec_name: DVCPRO HD 1080i50
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0.2(eng): Data: unknown (tmcd)
```

I can see from MediaInfo [image]

That the Audio is Muxed into the video. I'm trying to re-wrap this into an XDCAM, and copy over the audio streams. The problem is that I don't know how to map the audio that is wrapped into the video?

This is the command I have so far:

```
ffmbc -threads 8 -i "input.mov" -threads 8 -tff  
-pix_fmt yuv422p -vcodec mpeg2video -timecode 09:59:50:00 
.. other tags omitted ..

-acodec pcm_s24le 
-map_audio_channel 0.1:0-0.1:0 
-map_audio_channel 0.1:1-0.1:1 
-f mov -y "output.mov"  
-acodec pcm_s24le 
-map_audio_channel 0.2:0-0.2:0 
-map_audio_channel 0.2:1-0.2:1 -newaudio
```

When executed this returns "Cannot find audio channel 0.2.0". I changed the input stream identifier to stream 0, and 1 for the audios. Which when executed returned "Cannot find audio channel #0.0.0" presumably because it's trying to find a audio channel within the video stream?

How can I extract the audio from this file?

You may notice I'm using FFMBC, not FFMPEG ( there is no tag for FFMBC ), but I imagine it's the same for both. I'm not constrained to FFMBC, I can move to FFMPEG if it has a solution.

Thanks

Comment: do you want code or do you just want the audio from this file? you can import the movie file to windows movie maker and then save as audio only?

Comment: or you could upload it to dropbox and then paste the share link in to http://www.mp3grabber.net/

Comment: Code please, this is not a one off, it will be put into a workflow to process lots of files.

Comment: ffmpeg -vn  -a copy     to ignore the video and just copy the PCM audio . Output should just have audio track

Comment: @RobertRowntree I like this idea. It means that my transcode to IMX50 is a two step process, but it gets the job done, not a big deal. Extracting just the audio now, I'll let you know how it goes with the re-wrap.

Comment: You should show your actual command and the complete console output. Why are you using `ffmbc` instead of `ffmpeg`? Mapping is easier and more flexible in `ffmpeg` than in `ffmbc`, IIRC.